# Upload Image to Parse is not working

Tags: android, image, file-upload, parse-platform, image-uploading

I have a "save" button that will upload an image to parse. It used to work really well. But for some reason, it stops working.

When I press the button, nothing happens. As if the code ignored the onClick method. I thought something is wrong with the button or the other objects being saved. So I disabled every single object and found out it works fine when I disabled the image uploading.

So if I disable the image uploading, I can still save the name. But when I enable the image uploading, nothing happens and it feels like the onClick method is being ignored.

This is very weird. I haven't changed anything in my code and now it's not working. It used to work.

Do you guys have any idea what's wrong?

This is the updated code with logs:

```
protected Button mSavePet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Save);

    mSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("Log", "save button clicked");
            myUploading();
        }
    });
}


private void myUploading() {
    Log.d("Log", "myUploadig Start");

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 3, stream);
    byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    String currentUserUsername = currentUser.getUsername();

    //get the new pet info
    String petname = mPetName.getText().toString();

    Log.d("Log", "puting objects start");
        //Save Pet to the cloud
        final ParseObject petObject = new ParseObject("MyPets");
        petObject.put("petName", petname);
        petObject.put("user", currentUserUsername);

        // Create the ParseFile for Image
        final ParseFile file = new ParseFile("petImage.png", image);
        // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
        file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                Log.d("Log", "SaveFileInBackground Start");
                if(e == null){

                    Log.d("Log", "Putting ImageFile Start");
                    // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
                    petObject.put("petImage", file);

                    // Create the class and the columns
                    petObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Log.d("Log", "putting objects finished");
                                finish();
                            } else {
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is the code output:

```
08-06 20:04:56.117  29376-29376/com.example.stanleysantoso.wikipetia D/Log﹕ save button clicked
08-06 20:04:56.129  29376-29376/com.example.stanleysantoso.wikipetia D/Log﹕ myUploadig Start
08-06 20:05:08.008  29376-29376/com.example.stanleysantoso.wikipetia D/Log﹕ puting objects start
08-06 20:07:06.986  29376-29376/com.example.stanleysantoso.wikipetia D/Log﹕ save button clicked
08-06 20:07:06.986  29376-29376/com.example.stanleysantoso.wikipetia D/Log﹕ myUploadig Start
08-06 20:07:16.972  29376-29376/com.example.stanleysantoso.wikipetia D/Log﹕ puting objects start
```

so, it never went in file.saveInBackGround.

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to call `file.saveInBackground();` and in the next line `Object.put("Image", file);`. As `saveInBackground()` is asynchronous it is probably finishes after you're trying to put this file object to Object. Try to add callback and move this code to callback:

```
file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback callback() {
    @Override()
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Object.put("Image", file);

            // Create the class and the columns
            petObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        finish();
                    } else {

                    }
               }
            });
        } else {
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code. it doesn't work. it acts the same way. it's like the code is being ignored. when I press the button, the app takes a few seconds to think and then it goes back to its original state. I know it's thinking because I cannot access the editText durng that time.

Comment: Did you tried and debug execution? Where does the execution stops?

Comment: or you can add log outputs after various steps and look which one is last - that will help to find the point where the execution breaks

Comment: I am unable to debug my app. for some reason the debug is not attached. and the debuging window is not there. do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand how to do debuging. Can you refer me somewhere or tell me what should I be looking for? I know how to use the red dot and to go line by line. but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: add `Log.d("some_tag", "bitmap compressed");` etc after various operations including callbacks of asynchronous method and in the logcat window you'll see these messages. The order of these messages will tell you the order of the execution and if somewhere execution will stop you'll see where - these lines would be missing

Comment: It seems like there is no problem with the code. it goes all the way till the end but stops right before finish(). Is it possible that this is happening because the internet connection is bad or slow? and because the imagefile is big, it stops working?

Comment: @stanleysantoso did you check whether exception is null there?

Comment: Yes exception is null. Oh and when I was trying things out, I managed to upload and image once. And I did not change anything. I was just putting my logs. Thats why I assumed maybe it's because of internet connection

Comment: This is getting weird. I tried 30 for the compression instead of 100. still not working. is there a way to solve this?

Comment: so, I redid my code, apparently, it never went into file.saveInBackground(). any idea why?

Comment: @stanleysantoso can you edit your question and provide reworked code? with logcat output

Comment: I've provided the new code along with logcat output.

Comment: if you remove ` final ParseObject petObject = new ParseObject("MyPets");
        petObject.put("petName", petname);
        petObject.put("user", currentUserUsername);` what's happened?

Comment: I think it will crash. Parseobject is important since it is required to save objects into parse classes.

Comment: it will also give me an error since I have nothing to refer for the "petObject" that is inside of file.saveInBackground.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But just to check whether file saving still don't starts

Comment: Well. If it gives me an error, i cannot run the app.

Comment: So remove all code responsible for saving pet object from file save callback

Comment: Tried it. still stuck with "puting object start" as the last log. doesn't go to file.saveInBackground.

Comment: so... what's the solution?